# Rails simple_form label_html

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, css, label, simple-form

I'd like to override the margin between the input & its label on one form -- can this be done via :label_html => .... ?  The example on github shows a :class => 'special' being passed.  Do I need to set up something in my .css file?  if so, how would I do that (meaning, do I label it with a ., or a #, or nothing)?  The css I've got has a "simple_form label" with some settings, I'm guessing I need to do something similar, but I'm just having difficulty putting the pieces together..

Thanks

Comment: can you show an example of the code u have so far? please add it to your question

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Styling is done in your stylesheet. A selector for your label would be

```
.simple_form label.special
```

Because it is placed inside a form with `simple_form` class, it's tag is `label` and it's class is `special`. So you will write something like this in your css file:

```
.simple_form label.special {
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Note that spaces in selectors are important. `label .special` and `label.special` are very different.